# Azure Search querying json metadata

Tags: lucene.net, azure-cognitive-search

I have indexed documents with a "MetadataFields" key whose values are json.

"MetadataFields": "{"continent":"north america","country":"united states","region":"x34","tagnumber":"abc-123"}

I'm able to search for a specific match in Search Explorer using
MetadataFields/tagnumber:abc-123

But I cannot figure out how to find documents where this attribute is null or missing.  Is this possible?  What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Cognitive Search, you can use [filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-filters) to find null items.

In Search Explorer, the syntax would look like this:

```
$filter=MetadataFields/tagnumber eq null
```

To do this, you would need to have the field `tagnumber` marked as `filterable` in your index definition.